SvelteKit doesn't deploy properly, what do I change?
I developed and app in SvelteKit, and I wanna deploy it as a static site. This is my SSG adapter configuration I got from the documentation.
const config={
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown. On some platforms
            // these options are set automatically — see below
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: undefined,
            precompress: false,
            strict: false
        })
    }
};

The problem here is that when I try 'npm run build' it puts up a bunch of files but no HTML or CSS files, also when I try npm run preview it can't find the main CSS file. If I change strict to true it gives me an error that I should prerender routes. If I export const prerender = true; in +page.svelte it ignores it, I created +page.js specially for that line but it gives me another error:

node:internal/event_target:1010
process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
Error: 404 /src/app.css (linked from /)

How do I navigate this?

In the docs it instructs you to add export const prerender = true; to src/routes/+layout.js. If you add it to src/routes/+page.js, then it's only that page that will be pre-rendered (I assume). By adding to the layout instead, it will be applied to all pages that uses that layout.

Regarding the CSS error, where is the CSS file located, and how do you import it to your main app?

@PeppeL-G the CSS file is in src/app.css, and I tagged it normally in the app.html file as if it's a static site.
as for the pretender, it doesn't matter if it's called page or layout, they throw the same error.

After many suggestions and many searches, none of the solutions worked. So I simply copied the output files from .svelte-kit folder and uploaded them directly to the server. it took some tweaking in the middle with the linking of some files but it worked out in the end. This method is not recommended, I did this out of sheer frustration.

I'm also trying to find how to do it. SvelteKit documentation is absolutely horrible

I'm not 100% sure about this answer, but I think you have two options.
Option 1

Put the CSS file somewhere in the src folder, or any of its sub-folders (whatever you prefer).
In src/routes/+layout.svelte, add the following to your <script> element:
import "./the-path-to-the-file.css"



Option 2

Put the CSS file in the src/static folder (or any of its sub-folders, whatever you prefer)
Add the following HTML code to the <head> element in the src/app.html file:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%sveltekit.assets%/the-path-to-the-file.css">




Option 2 is making progress, it builds with a CSS file on it but no HTML,when I run 'npm run preview' it gives me an error that manifest.js is not found. I went through the .svelte-kit directory and it turns out that when I run 'npm run build' it creates manifest-full.js, how do I change the configuration?

I have never encountered a manifest.json file like that in a SvelteKit project before, but see if you can get any help from the SO question Module not found when running vite preview for SvelteKit project.
